# OWASP ZAP against Netlify password protected site

Tags: netlify, zap

I need to run OWASP ZAP against one of our sites running on Netlify, but it is password protected (see screenshot for what I mean). For those who don't know how it works, when you visit the site, Netlify returns a 401 with the response of the request being the form. The form takes a password (input name is `password`) and POSTs it to the same URL (so https://myapp.netlify.app/ returns 401 and then the form POSTs it to https://myapp.netlify.app). I've created the context that *should* work, but I don't think it likes the 401 being returned as the same URL as the POST.

I'm sure I'm just doing a really stupid thing, but here is the relevant snippet from the config:

```xml
<authentication>
    <type>2</type>
    <strategy>EACH_RESP</strategy>
    <pollurl/>
    <polldata/>
    <pollheaders/>
    <pollfreq>60</pollfreq>
    <pollunits>REQUESTS</pollunits>
    <form>
        <loginurl>https://myapp.netlify.app</loginurl>
        <loginbody>password={%password%}</loginbody>
        <loginpageurl>https://myapp.netlify.app</loginpageurl>
    </form>
</authentication>
```

I also tried this snippet, in case it required the username (the UI kept enforcing the use of username):

```xml
<authentication>
    <type>2</type>
    <strategy>EACH_RESP</strategy>
    <pollurl/>
    <polldata/>
    <pollheaders/>
    <pollfreq>60</pollfreq>
    <pollunits>REQUESTS</pollunits>
    <form>
        <loginurl>https://myapp.netlify.app</loginurl>
        <loginbody>username={%username%}&amp;password={%password%}</loginbody>
        <loginpageurl>https://myapp.netlify.app</loginpageurl>
    </form>
</authentication>
```

[image: Netlify password protected site form]

Comment: Debugging authentication is _really_ hard of you dont have access to the app. My recommendation is to set up authentication in the desktop then test it with forced user mode. You can then see exactly which requests ZAP sends and what the responses are. Compare that with a working flow and see what the differences are. Its probably easier to support you via the ZAP User Group TBH: https://groups.google.com/group/zaproxy-users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

School boy error. I had everything configured properly, but wasn't providing the user (I thought the forced user would be picked up).

Running `zap-baseline.py -t https://myapp.netlify.app/ -r testreport.html -n /zap/wrk/myapp.context -U testuser` works.